# Users are not allowed to register accounts so quickly

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, ejabberd, user-registration

I'm using ejabberd 2.1.11 to implement chat in my iOS app. The problem I'm facing is that after registering a user, I have to wait for 10 minutes to register another user.

```
%% In-band registration
{access, register, [{allow, all}]}.
{registration_timeout,infinity}.
```

This is what I'm using in my config file, but still I get the same below error.

```xml
<error code="500" type="wait">
    <resource-constraint xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
    <text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">Users are not allowed to register accounts so quickly</text>
</error>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same issue, the root cause was that we had an extra space in front of the registration_timeout config in ejabberd.yml. After removing the extra space, the value was correctly read from the config. You can verify it by attaching to ejabberd console(sudo ejabberdctl debug) and execute the following code:

```
ejabberd_config:get_option(
     registration_timeout,
            fun(TO) when is_integer(TO), TO > 0 ->
                    TO;
               (infinity) ->
                    infinity;
               (unlimited) ->
                    infinity
            end, 600).
```

This is the same code that loads this value in mod_register.